# How to prevent a mouseout after an click in D3?

Tags: d3.js, onclick, toggle, mouseout

I am working on developing a force directed graph in D3. Right now when I mouseover nodes it changes the opacity of the connected links from 0 to 1 and then when I mouseout it returns the opacity back to 0.

That works fine but what I am having trouble with is making a click on the node maintain the opacity of the links at 1 even after the mouseout event. Then I want to be able to click on other nodes to make their links opacity 1 as well. Then also be able to click on the some of the previously clicked nodes to be able to return the opacity of their associated links to 0.

In short, I want to be able to toggle the opacity of the associated links of a node with out it being affect by mouseout events. A sample of my current code is below. I am thinking I might have to set a new id to toggle on and off when I click on a node?

```
var nodeClick = function(d) {
    svg.selectAll(".link")
    .filter(function(p) { 
          return _(d.facets).contains(p.target.name)
    })
    .transition()
    .style('stroke-opacity', 0.9);
};

var overText1 = function(d) {
    svg.selectAll(".link")
    .filter(function(p) { 
          return _(d.facets).contains(p.target.name)
    })
    .transition()
    .style('stroke-opacity', 0.9);
};

var overText0 = function(d) {
        svg.selectAll(".link")
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style('stroke-opacity', 0);
    };

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", function (d) {
        return d.group === 1 ? "nodeBig" : "node";
    })
    .attr("r", function(d) {return d.radius })
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        return color(d.group);
    })
    .on("mouseover", overText1)
    .on('click', nodeClick)
    .on('mouseout', overText0)
    .call(force.drag);
```

Comment: In your click handler, you could set a specific attribute for the affected links and then check that in your mouseout handler.

Answer (score 0):

I actually finally figured this out on my own. I created a lock field that accepts either a "true" or "false". Then I put an if statement in the mouseoff function that only enables mouseoff functionality on elements that don't have "true" in their lock field.